# On the genus of thin knots.

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I came across this papper by [JA Baldwin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5199&ved=0ahUKEwjb4aTA4dfVAhVBCBoKHWuSCfUQFggjMAE&usg=AFQjCNHhVEzSJnMV1CzMzfuHBC_IV1QB1Q) which presents a combinatorial definition for the knot Floer homology.

At a certain paragraph of the third page the author makes the next statement: the genus of a homologically thin knot is the degree of its Alexander polynomial.

I just want to make sure that the author does mean the genus I know, namely the minimal genus taken over all spaning surfaces of the knot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert_surface#Genus_of_a_knot) is the minimal genus taken over all Seifert surfaces of the knot (i.e. over all oriented spanning surfaces of the knot). Ozsvath and Szabo prove (in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311496)) that the genus of a knot is the maximum Alexander grading in which the knot Floer homology is non-trivial. If the knot Floer homology of a knot is thin, then the degree of the Alexander polynomial is equal to the maximum Alexander grading in which the knot Floer homology is non-trivial (and thus it is also equal to the genus of the knot).